# Check number of pairs in KeyValuePair list

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, key-value

I have this thing here

```
var filelist = new List< KeyValuePair< string, string>>();
```

and I'd like to know if there's any command like `filelist.Amount` or something that checks the number of entries in the list.

Comment: have you considered using a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [List.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) property. So, in your case, it would be:

```
int numberOfEntries = filelist.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `List<T>` class exposes a [`Count` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) that tells you the total number of elements contained in the list.

So all you have to write is:

```
var fileList = new List< KeyValuePair< string, string>>();
int amount = fileList.Count;
```

Note that the `Count` property is different from the related [`Capacity` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx). `Capacity` tells you the total number of elements that the internal data structure used to implement the `List<T>` can hold before it must resize itself (which happens automatically). `Count` tells you the *actual* number of items.

Comment: if Count is a property, then it shouldn't have parenthesis `()` behind it!

Comment: Nor should it have a random space after the name of the variable. Obviously I can't code without an IDE!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx)